# Shouldn't this work? (typecast / unboxing)

Tags: c#

```
public IList A23 { get; set; }

s.A23 = new List<int>(new int[] { 62, 63, 64 });

IList g = s.A23;
double d = (double)g[0];
```

the double cast on the last line throws an exception. g[0] should be an object (of an int), which is castable to a double.

I know that this works:

```
double d = (double)(int)g[0];
```

But that isn't my question :). I'm working on a runtime thing which is beyond the scope of this post. Since the source is an IList, I don't know the type that's in there. I would have thought the compiler could cast the object without unboxing as an int first??

Answer (score 4):

> the double cast on the last line throws an exception

That's correct. A boxed T may only be unboxed to T or T?.

> I would have thought the compiler could cast the object without unboxing as an int first

OK, you're building a runtime, so it will build character for you to work this out. **Carefully describe the code you expected the compiler to emit**, remembering that of course the compiler does not know there's an int in there.

Extremely helpful hint: If the boxed object is typed as *dynamic* instead of *object* then the cast to double succeeds.  That is `(double)(dynamic)(g[0])` works as you expect.  "Dynamic" is just "object" with a funny hat on, so why does one fail and the other succeed?

Comment: Ok, so the dynamic cast does work, but the IL it generates is a little too messy for my needs. Right now I do: "emit call _miItem" to get the item and that part works. Is there a way to "simulate" what dynamic does. I.e. after I call _miItem, call GetType() on it and then unbox the result of the miItem as the result of GetType()? Seems like OpCodes.UnboxAny requires a "hardcoded" type?

Comment: @SledgeHammer: You've discovered that the generated code for what you want is awful, and your question is "is there a better way to do it?" *If I knew of a better way, don't you think we would have generated that code?*

Comment: @SledgeHammer: Now, there are things you could do here that are narrow-focused on the fact that you're casting to double. You could use the `Convert.ToDouble` method, for instance.  `dynamic` does not do that because `dynamic` must do *what the C# compiler would do*, and `ToDouble` does not do what the C# compiler does. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: your 2nd response was getting to what I was asking... dynamic has to do a *lot* which I don't... what my end game is, is to take an IList and foreach on it to a destination array I create. The source I know is an IList and destination is type X (in this case a double, but could also be a long, etc. for example... anything that makes sense). So the array I create is of type X, but the unboxing doesn't work in this case because of the mismatched types... I kind of want to do what Convert.ChangeType does, minus the huge performance hit.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe calling Convert.ChangeType() will work... benchmarked it and the (double)(int) conversion was 4ms vs. ChangeType() 48ms on 1M iterations... so a little bit of a hit... unless I find a better way... but at the very least, I can maybe special case the emit code to only go this route if the source is an IList.

Comment: @SledgeHammer: Again, consider what code you would have to write if you were the person writing ChangeType, remembering that you don't know what the source type is. If there were a way to write that code more efficiently, they already would have.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot. Unboxing is not casting. You need to unbox the variable and then cast it. In this special case this means two casts.

When you cast to `double` the runtime (not the compiler!) does not know how to cast the `object` to `double`, and doesn't try to unbox it either, because there's nothing that says you want that. In fact, it would be perfectly plausible that you want the `object` to be cast, and not the boxed variable. The intent of your code is ambiguous and the designers may have decided to throw it altogether.

Comment: That's a plausible guess, but not quite right. The ambiguity isn't the real problem here.

Comment: Yes, when I said "**may** have decided" I was guessing :)

Comment: See if you and SledgeHammer can work out the actual reason for the restriction that an unbox must unbox to the actual type. (Or nullable.)